# What are the physics challenges of rain farming

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science

Rain farming is an engineering concept, employing the technology of industrial cooling towers, to deliver vast amounts of water to the lower levels of the troposphere as warm moist air. This question is about the challenges to such an idea that might be presented by physics.

The objective of rain farming is to deliver predictable rainfall to the region, for the benefit of agriculture and municipal hygiene.  While the cloud physics are complex, there is a well documented history of tall cooling towers generating, usually unproductive, clouds. An additional objective of rain farming is to normalize regional hydrology, and to increase the stock of fresh water for the region by sourcing the water, for uplift to the troposphere, from briny sources such as oceans, non-potable underground resources, or flood plains.

What constraints would be imposed on such an endeavour by the energetics of evaporation and condensation, atmospheric dynamics, etc.?

Comment: I've edited to emphasise the physics part of the question. Perhaps it could be re-opened? (I generally like it when we get atmospheric physics questions here.)

Comment: Your edit definitely makes the question more physics-y, but in its new form it doesn't seem specific enough to me. We'll see what others think.

Comment: @Nathaniel your edit is way better but I feel like the question is still too broad and really about an engineering problem.